# fancybox - resizing image inside the iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox version 2.1.5
What I am trying to do is display large images in the fancybox iframe of about width 900 and height 500. Of course right now images render huge and don't fit into that iframe.
I am having a hard time capturing the right class or a way to navigate to the image to resize it. What I tried is using beforeShow function and do this:

```
                 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                    type: 'iframe',
                    href: source,
                    title: title,
                    width: 900,
                    height: 500,
                    closeBtn: false,
                    nextSpeed: 0, //important
                    prevSpeed: 0, //important
                    beforeShow: function() {
                        alert('its working!');
                        $(".fancybox-iframe img").css("width","900px");
                        $(".fancybox-iframe img").css("height","auto");
                        $(".fancybox-iframe img").addClass("imageResize");
                    }
                });
```

However, neither `$(".fancybox-iframe img")` nor `$(".fancybox-inner img")` are correct ways to trigger the img.
How can I use `beforeShow` function to properly resize my images inside the fancybox iframe.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
                    beforeShow: function () {
                        var newWidth = 900; // set new image display width
                        $('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('img').css({
                            width  : newWidth,
                            height : "auto"
                        }); // apply new size to img
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for me using fancybox 3 i was having an issue with the fancybox iframe not being loaded, so this helped:

This code polls the iframe for an img tag every 100msec for up to 2 seconds to see if an image has been loaded.  if it has then it sets the attributes of the image to be max height.

If an iframe isn't found, then it should clear the interval straight away.

```
var fancyboxOptions = {
    onComplete: function( instance, slide ) {
        var timeCompleted = new Date();
        function afterLoading () {
            clearInterval(pollLoaded);
            $('iframe',slide.$content[0]).contents().find('img').attr('height','100%');
        }
        var pollLoaded = setInterval(function(){
            var iframe = document.getElementById($('iframe',slide.$content[0]).attr('id'));
            var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
            if (iframeDoc) {
                if (( iframeDoc.readyState  === 'complete' )
                    && ($('iframe',slide.$content[0]).contents().find('img').length > 0)) {
                    afterLoading();
                }
                // try for 2 seconds then stop.
                if (new Date() - timeCompleted > 2000) {
                    clearInterval(pollLoaded);
                }
            }
            else {
                clearInterval(pollLoaded);
            }
        },100);
    }

};
```